# SQL search query not working when i set the ORDER DESC

Tags: sql-order-by

I have some customer info results displayed in a table. They are in ascending order so i have to scroll down to the bottom to get to the last one that registered. Or I can type the name, ID, or phone number to search for it. Everything works fine. Now i tried to change the order so i have the last one on the top...I placed ORDER BY id DESC right after WHERE 1 in the first line of the code...when i do that I get the desired order but the search stops working-syntax error. How can i change the order and still have the search query working. Im a PHP rookie.

The PHP Code

```
<?php           
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_kontaktne_informacie WHERE 1";

if($meno_a_priezvisko!=""){ $query.=" AND meno_a_priezvisko LIKE '%".$meno_a_priezvisko."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";}

if($nazov_firmy!=""){ $query.=" AND nazov_firmy LIKE '%".$nazov_firmy."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";}

if($ico_firmy!=""){ $query.=" AND ico_firmy LIKE '%".$ico_firmy."%' ";}

if($telefon!=""){ $query.=" AND telefon LIKE '%".$telefon."%' ";}

if($referencny_kod!=""){ $query.=" AND referencny_kod LIKE '%".$referencny_kod."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";
;}


mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));    
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<tr class="databaza_uzivatelov_riadok" onclick="window.location=\'formular_databaza_kontaktov_kontakt.php?id='.$line["id"].'\'" >';

            echo '<td align="center">'.$pocet.'</td>';  
            echo "<td>".$line["meno_a_priezvisko"]."</td>";         
            echo "<td style='font-size:12px; padding-top:8px;'>".$line["nazov_firmy"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$line["ico_firmy"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$line["telefon"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$line["email"]."</td>"; 
            echo "<td><a class='ref' href=\"http://www.opravit.sk/ref.php?=".$line["referencny_kod"]. "\">".$line["referencny_kod"]."</a></td>";
            echo "<td>".$line["kredit"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $pocet ++;}     
?>
```

Comment: ```ORDER BY id DESC``` should be placed after the conditions.

Comment: If you could solve the problem please accept the answer that fixed your problem from below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the ORDER BY at the end of the query.

Syntax definition from [w3cschools.org](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

```
SQL ORDER BY Syntax
SELECT column_name, column_name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;
```

And here the code that should fix your problem:

```
  <?php           
  $query = "SELECT * FROM table_kontaktne_informacie WHERE 1";

  if($meno_a_priezvisko!=""){ $query.=" AND meno_a_priezvisko LIKE '%".$meno_a_priezvisko."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";}

  if($nazov_firmy!=""){ $query.=" AND nazov_firmy LIKE '%".$nazov_firmy."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";}

  if($ico_firmy!=""){ $query.=" AND ico_firmy LIKE '%".$ico_firmy."%' ";}

  if($telefon!=""){ $query.=" AND telefon LIKE '%".$telefon."%' ";}

  if($referencny_kod!=""){ $query.=" AND referencny_kod LIKE '%".$referencny_kod."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";

  $query.=" ORDER BY id DESC"

  ;}
```

Comment: thank you...i just placed the query after the last bracket in your code and it works fine now...cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the ORDER BY id DESC at the very last in your query.

```
...

if($referencny_kod!=""){ $query.=" AND referencny_kod LIKE '%".$referencny_kod."%' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci' ";}

$query .= " ORDER BY id DESC";

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

....
```